# Variable not substituted in procedure. What is happening?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have created a procedure such as the following

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE drop_if_exists (table_name IN varchar2)
IS
BEGIN
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE table_name';
EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
         IF SQLCODE != -942 THEN
             RAISE;
         END IF;
END;
```

When I run it as drop_if_exists ( 'my_table' ) it says everything was executed successfully, but any table called my_table will still exist after the call to the procedure. Changing to uppercase makes no difference. I guess that the variable simply is not substituted ... Any ideas on how to fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are dropping a table named "table_name", what is different to deleting the table you pass in the parameter.

Try this:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE ' || table_name ;
```

Anyway, I would NOT advice doing that. Your code is potentially dangerous.

Comment: For example, imagine that you do this: call drop_if_exists('my_table;SELECT * FROM USERS');

Comment: Actually, SQL Injection is more difficult (not impossible by any stretch) when concatenating strings with object names; to guard against it you can use the [dbms_assert](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_assert.htm) package.

Comment: It's a command line script run against a database that is not used by any external application. I am not too worried :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE ' ||table_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is wrong actually, you should do it like this:

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE ' || table_name;
where table_name is the parameter which contains the name of the table and not string as you are trying in your example